# Removing Frame Border from USGS scanned images in ArcGIS with Python?

Tags: arcpy, raster, usgs

I have a couple of USGS scanned maps like [image: USGS Scanned map]

I want to remove the frame border from these images so that I can use them in ArcGIS.

Is there algorithm or python script that I can run to remove the borders or get the extents of the actual data?

Comment: Do you have access to a graphical package? like photoshop?

Comment: USGS have orthorectified mosaics ready to download from http://earthexplorer.usgs.gov/

Comment: I need to do the process on a batch of scanned maps (>50). Using Photoshop would be time consuming. I do know about the mosaics but these are maps without any spatial references and finding the corresponding mosaic would be really difficult.

Comment: @pyNovice I don't have a real solution, but you might check out: http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php I've heard good things about it.